# autosizing sql server database diagram view

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-diagramming

i see there is "arrange tables" that organizes your table relationships to be clear.  is there anyway to autosize the tables so it shows:

1. the full name of the table
2. the full height to show all fields.

i find myself tweaking tables over and over manually and its a pain.  I would hope there would be some way to auto correct the sizing of all tables in the diagram with one click.  maybe i am too hopeful.

Comment: The diagramming functionality with SQL Server is pretty poor I'm afraid but probably good enough for what it is intended for. There are utilities out there that do a better job if all you want to do is output a database diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN SQL Server 2005 (and, if I recall right, 2000), first select the table or tables you wish to adjust, and then select "Autosize Selected Tables" from the right-click menu or the "Database Diagram" menu. There does not appear to be a matching toolbar button.

Despite this, in 2005 I find I sometimes need to manually widen the "column name" column so that, when it prints, my entire column is printed. Similarly, I sometimes have to widen the table window (horizontally and/or vertically), to ensure that scroll bars are not included in the printout for each window.

The tool is useful in 2000, but they made it a bit less useful and much more irritating in 2005. I haven't used it yet in 2008.

Two more cents: I used Erwin a bit and hated it. I used Embarcaderos' ER Studio a bit and loved it. Both cost major money, so you may well have to make do with diagrams.

Answer (score -1):

The diagramming functionality with SQL Server is pretty poor I'm afraid but probably good enough for what it is intended for (creating relationships). There are utilities out there that do a better job if all you want to do is output a database diagram e.g. Visio.

If I remember correctly there is REDGATE who do a range of utilities for SQL Server.

http://www.red-gate.com